# Appengine logservice with remote_api

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging, remoteapi

I am trying to get my appengine application logs from remote.
I am using remote_api, I tried with appcfg but I discarded it because it has a limit on the download/buffer so I can't download all the logs.

Now I am using the logservice, but if I use it in my code it doesn't return anything.
Here is my code:

```
import time


import urllib2

from google.appengine.ext.remote_api import remote_api_stub
from google.appengine.api.logservice import logservice

import getpass
import base64
import os
from appcfg import *
import getpass
import subprocess

os.environ['HTTP_X_APPENGINE_TASKRETRYCOUNT']='1'
os.environ["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = "Developement"
os.environ['HTTP_HOST'] = 'unitTest'
os.environ['CURRENT_MODULE_ID']='default'
os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']='1.0'


email_address = "iacopo@indiegala.com"
application_url = "store-indiegala.appspot.com"
def aut():
    app_name = "store-indiegala.appspot.com"
    f = lambda : ("*EMAIL*", "*PASSWORD*")
    remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApi(None, '/_ah/remote_api', auth_func,app_name)
    print("successfully authenticated")

    fetch_logs()


def fetch_logs():
    end_time = time.time()
    print ("starting")
    for req_log in logservice.fetch(end_time = end_time, offset = None, minimum_log_level = logservice.LOG_LEVEL_INFO, 
                include_app_logs=True, include_incomplete=True):
    print req_log.ip


def auth_func():
   global email_address
   return (email_address, getpass.getpass('Password:'))




aut()
```

It successfully connects to my app and he make the logservice.fetch(), but it returns an empty object... why?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your [logs](https://appengine.google.com/logs) in the App Engine admin and make sure you have the right **module** and **version**.  They can be found in each log entry, for example:

`2015-01-24 21:58:43.425 / active start=2015-01-24,13:57:36.773 AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=baseline`

Becomes:

```
import os
os.environ["CURRENT_MODULE_ID"] = "default"
os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']=  "baseline"`
```